# Can I use CSS content and counters to add custom labels to my grid?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-content

I'm currently creating a html grid out of `div`s to display a characters attributes.

[image: How the CSS is laid out]

Here is the DIV:

```
<div class="grid attributes ng-scope">
    <!-- ngRepeat: (category, attribute) in mages[0].attributes --><div ng-repeat="(category, attribute) in mages[0].attributes" ng-init="categoryIndex = $index" class="col-0 mental grid">
        <h5 class="category-header ng-binding">mental</h5>
        <!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-0 col-0-0 Intelligence attribute">
            Intelligence: 1
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-1 col-0-1 Resolve attribute">
            Resolve: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-2 col-0-2 Wits attribute">
            Wits: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute -->
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (category, attribute) in mages[0].attributes --><div ng-repeat="(category, attribute) in mages[0].attributes" ng-init="categoryIndex = $index" class="col-1 physical grid">
        <h5 class="category-header ng-binding">physical</h5>
        <!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-0 col-1-0 Dexterity attribute">
            Dexterity: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-1 col-1-1 Stamina attribute">
            Stamina: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-2 col-1-2 Strength attribute">
            Strength: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute -->
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (category, attribute) in mages[0].attributes --><div ng-repeat="(category, attribute) in mages[0].attributes" ng-init="categoryIndex = $index" class="col-2 social grid">
        <h5 class="category-header ng-binding">social</h5>
        <!-- ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-0 col-2-0 Composure attribute">
            Composure: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-1 col-2-1 Manipulation attribute">
            Manipulation: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute --><div ng-repeat="(key, value) in  attribute" class="row-2 col-2-2 Presence attribute">
            Presence: 0
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, value) in  attribute -->
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: (category, attribute) in mages[0].attributes -->
</div>
```

Is it possible to label the rows using CSS `content` chicanery?

Something like (CSS pseudocode below):

```
body{
    counter-reset: attr;
}


.attributes> [class*='col-0-']:before {

  content: label(attr);
}
```

Where label is something that holds my labels in an ordered list/dict? Or is this a job for SASS/SCSS type stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS counters can only work with the `counter()` and `counters()` functions. They are numeric values that are incremented and tracked entirely within CSS, and can only be rendered as numeric values.

The `content` property can take an attribute value from the originating HTML element via the `attr()` function without having to use counters.

But if your desired values are coming from elsewhere, such as a JavaScript object, then unless you can express them in custom data attributes, you will need JavaScript to render them into the page.

Custom data attributes would work like so:

```css
[data-foo]:before {
    content: attr(data-foo);
}
```

```html
<div data-foo="Power">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: You mention *custom data attributes*, how would that work? Do you mean have them as `<div foo="Power">` and then `bar:before{content:"attr(foo)"}` ?

Comment: @Pureferret: Yes, albeit `data-foo` with the prefix, and without the quotes in `attr()`.